# Prevent overlay and n.fn.init

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check for multiple divs if inside divs are overlaying. But I cant get the element specific.

Here is the foreach function for every div

```
function check_overlay(){
    //check if divs are overlaying
    $("#mytest[data-item-id]").each(function() {    
        var id_item = $(this).data('item-id');
        console.log(id_item);
        var content = $("#content"+id_item); 
        var rating = $("#rating"+id_item);

        var status = collision(content,rating);
        console.log(content) ====> here i'm getting [object Object]
        if(status){
            console.log(status);
            console.log($(this).data('item-id-flex'));         

       }
    });
}
```

Here is the collision function

```
function collision($div1, $div2) {

    var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
    var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
    var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
    var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
    var b1 = y1 + h1;
    var r1 = x1 + w1;
    var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
    var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
    var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
    var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
    var b2 = y2 + h2;
    var r2 = x2 + w2;

    if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
    return true;
}
```

And the divs are appended with AJAX like this

```
$.each(item, function() {
 var item_id = this.id;
    var elements= '<div id="mytest" data-item-id="'+ item_id +'" class="row">' +
        '<div id="#content'+ item_id +'" class="col-xs-12 ">' +
             '<h2 class="col-xs-12 ">'+ name +'</h2>' +
         '</div>' +    
          '<div id="#rating'+item_id +'" class="col-xs-12">' +
              '<p class="col-xs-6 ">HELLLO</p>' +
          '</div>' +
         '</div>';

});

$(elements).insertBefore('#loadingDiv');
```

I am so disperated...I don't know what can I do..

**UPDATE**

What I need

```
[div#content255215252251521558.col-xs-12.content-div.no-padding, context: document, selector: "#content255215252251521558"]
```

What now looks

```
n.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#content255215252251521558"}
```

Comment: `content` is a jQuery object. What are you expecting to see when you log it?

Comment: Your `$.each` loop never appends anything. It just assigns the variable `elements`, but doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: @Barmar looks my edit please

Comment: You're overwriting the `elements` variable each time through the loop, so you'll only insert the last one.

Comment: @Barmar The elements are inserting on DOM very well..but I'm in trouble with overlay function. Because the parameters i'm sending to function are not good

Comment: Did you mean to concatenate them with `elements +=`?

Comment: You're never checking the value of the `status` variable.

Comment: Yes it's concatenate

Comment: Did you mean to write `console.log(status)`?

Comment: Why do you assign the `content` and `rating` variables, but instead of using them you rewrite the same expression when you call `collision()`? It should be `collision(content, rating)`

Comment: @Barmer i've made another update... but the proble still workings...the erorr i've got from function collision is:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined